# Python 3.5 how to implement this while loop or for loop

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm super new to programming and I'm learning python.  I am excited to announce that I have written 3 short programs so far.  I am experimenting with while and for loops but can't get either implemented into my programs.  Here is my pseudocode trying to use a for loop for the first time.

Declare count

Run leapyearprogram3

Count + 1 = Count

Go back to line 2

I appreciate that there are multiple ways of doing this (range, xrange, while, etc.) and I am trying to understand how a for loop works and how to implement it in more than just the following code.

```
# My leap year Python program.
# This program demonstrates the following:
# Determines if a user input of year is a leap year using the calendar 
# function 
#
# Author: Thomas Schuhriemen
# Course: CIS1400

import calendar
t1= int(input())
print ("Welcome to my leap year program")
print ("You may type any year and I will tell you if it is a leap year")

# some of the following is based on code written by INDIAN VILLAN on 
# comments on w3resource.com
# 3.0 is a stable build but this one (4.1) is experimenting with for to 
# repeat the question.

count = 0
for count >= 5:

    if calendar.isleap(t1) is True:
        print (t1, "is a leap year.")
else:
    print (t1, "is not a leap year.")
    count = count + 1
```

I can't seem to grasp why this keeps giving me errors.  I have given me an error saying there is something wrong with the code immediately following the for command the code it says "for count >= 5 & count <= 0:" has an invalid syntax error highlighting the 
"="

Thank you for your interest in helping me learn how to use for!

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive, please fix the indentation first.

Comment: None of this is valid Python code. Please use the formatting tools available to you to ensure that what we see is exactly what you have. Also, format your pseudo code.

Comment: And finally provide the full error message you get once your indentation is fixed. After that we will be glad to help!

Comment: First of all, pay attention to the basic ideas. What does `count >= 5 & count <= 0` even mean? I mean aside from Python, what is this line trying to do? How can anything be greater than 5 and less than 0?

Comment: Asking properly is very important. It may sound like nitpicking, but remember that we are not in your head. The more accurate and complete the picture, the greater the chance of getting useful help.

Comment: I removed the nonsense that FatihAkici was talking about.

Comment: @ThomasJoseph You also need to intend the `else` part properly.

Comment: Cool, @ThomasJoseph. If you want to use for, this is how to think about it: `for count in range(0, 5):`. This will do whatever is inside the loop for `count=0, count=1, ..., count=4`, so 5 times in total. Just do this, and indent your `else`, you're all set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import calendar
print ("Welcome to my leap year program")
print ("You may type any year and I will tell you if it is a leap year")

```
count = 0 
for i in range(5):
    count = count + i
    t1= int(input())
    if calendar.isleap(t1): # returns true if t1 is leap year else returns 
    false
        print (t1, "is a leap year.") # if test condition is true
    else:
        print (t1, "is not a leap year.") # if test condition is false
```

Answer (score 2):

Thomas. Don't worry about the harsh tries at the beginning of your journey. I suggest you take a look at The Python Tutorial, a tutorial for beginners, at the official Python documentation. [Here is the link to the explanation of the for loop.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

For now, keep this in mind: one of the most basic concepts of a programming language (in fact, even of human language) is the syntax. It means everything has its rightful place in a sentence, so a meaning can be taken out of this sentence.

In Python, the for loop has the following basic syntax:

```
for [variable] in [collection of things]:
    [block of code inside the loop]
```

Everything I put inside brackets you can modify. 
See that the words `for` and `in` (and also the colon at the end) are mandatory. You have to keep them in this setup.

As I said, take a look at The Python Tutorial, at your own pace, from the beginning to the end. It will give you a boost in learning Python through the best source of information: the official Python documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through this tutorial.  Are indentations used with a similar thought process as to when parenthesis are used?

Comment: @ThomasJoseph Yes. See this [guide](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3)

Comment: Python does not use parentheses nor brackets to nest code after if, while and for statements, for example. It uses indentation, that is simply some blank space in the beginning of the line (common use are 4 spaces). For further research:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Answer (score 1):

```
import calendar
print ("Welcome to my leap year program")
print ("You may type any year and I will tell you if it is a leap year")

count = 0 
for i in range(5):
    count = count + i
    t1= int(input())
    if calendar.isleap(t1): # returns true if t1 is leap year else returns 
false
        print (t1, "is a leap year.") # if test condition is true
    else:
        print (t1, "is not a leap year.") # if test condition is false
```

I learned proper syntax and I was able to come up with this.  Thanks everyone who posted suggestions on learning about for.

Comment: Cool! Now a food for thought is: What happens if the user enters a non-numeric input? Try and see it for yourself. How to "handle an exception in python"? (The question in quotes is the hint to start researching.) Well done, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The for loop syntax is wrong and there is no need to use it here. Refer the Python Wiki [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

```
import calendar
print ("Welcome to my leap year program")
print ("You may type any year and I will tell you if it is a leap year")

count = 0 
while count <= 5:
    t1= int(input())
    if calendar.isleap(t1): # returns true if t1 is leap year else returns false
        print (t1, "is a leap year.") # if test condition is true
    else:
        print (t1, "is not a leap year.") # if test condition is false 
    count = count + 1
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/FakeComposedNetbsd)